# Torre de Hanoy Python

Tags: python, recursión

Buenas tardes trato de hacer una tarea sobre la torre de hanoy el unico detalle que la comprobación para que sea mayor a 15 no lo estoy logrando el IF que tengo lo ignora.

```
def tower_of_hanoi(disks, source, auxiliary, target):  
    if(disks == 1): 
    
        print('Move disk 1 from rod {} to rod {}.'.format(source, target))  
        return  
    # function call itself  
    tower_of_hanoi(disks - 1, source, target, auxiliary)  
    print('Move disk {} from rod {} to rod {}.'.format(disks, source, target))  
    tower_of_hanoi(disks - 1, auxiliary, source, target)  
  
  
disks = int(input('Enter the number of disks: '))  
if int(disks) > 15:
            print("El número no debe ser mayor o igual a 15")

# We are referring source as A, auxiliary as B, and target as C  
tower_of_hanoi(disks, 'A', 'B', 'C')  # Calling the function
```

Alguna sugerencia de cambio de código es bienvenida.

Comment: Cual es el problema? Decir que no te funciona no ayuda a saber que es lo que ocurre.

Comment: Si corre el codigo pero no cumple la función de la restricción sobre un numero mayor a 15.  if int(disks) > 15:---- esta parte en especifico.

Comment: No te muestra el mensaje o que?

Comment: Corre sin problemas el codigo solo la restriccion sobre que sea menor a 5 la ignora, en pocas palabras

Comment: Por eso te pregunto si te muestra o no el mensaje. Lo que espero es que  el mensaje se te muestre pues luego de evaluar el `if` se cumpla o no, el programa seguirá su ejecución (que sería ejecutar la función). Si quieres que solo se ejecute la función cuando la condición no se cumple entonces colócala dentro de un bloque `else`

Comment: No muestra el mensaje del IF lo intente con un else y ahora si ya no corre no se si puedas mostrar un ejemplo. A lo que te refieres para integrarlo y poder resolver esto.

Comment: Buen día, copié y pegué tu código, lo probé con 16 y si muestra el mensaje, el error que comentas no es reproducible

Answer (score 1):

El error está en que siempre llamas `tower_of_hanoi` sin importar el valor ingresado.

El segmento corregido queda así:

```
disks = int(input('Enter the number of disks: '))
if int(disks) > 15:
    print("El número no debe ser mayor o igual a 15")
else:
    # We are referring source as A, auxiliary as B, and target as C
    tower_of_hanoi(disks, 'A', 'B', 'C')  # Calling the function
```

Comment: Mil gracias, ya me di cuenta donde estaba mi error